# Maximum input number to URL shortener

Tags: math, url-shortener

Given the following code which encodes a number - how can I calculate the maximum number if I want to limit the length of my generated keys. e.g. setting the max length of the result of `encode(num)` to some fixed value say 10

```
var alphabet = <SOME SET OF KEYS>,
    base = alphabet.length;

this.encode = function(num) {
    var str = '';
    while (num > 0) {
        str = _alphabet.charAt(num % base) + str;
        num = Math.floor(num / base);
    }
    return str;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are constructing `num`'s representation in base `base`, with some arbitrary set of characters as numerals (`alphabet`).

For n characters we can represent numbers 0 through `base`^n - 1, so the answer to your question is `base`^10 - 1. For example, using the decimal system, with 5 digits we can represent numbers from 0 to 99999 (10^5 - 1).

It's worth noting that you will not ever use some sub-n length strings such as '001' or '0405' (using the decimal system numerals) - so any string starting with the equivalent of 0 except '0' itself.

I imagine that, for the purpose of a URL shortener that is allowed variable length, this might be considered a waste. By using all combinations you could represent numbers 0 through `base`^(n+1) - 2, but it wouldn't be as straightforward as your scheme.